# Using custom markdown syntax with react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

I want to use custom syntax in my markdown files, and parse that into some particular HTML when I pass it to my ReactMarkdown component. For instance, if I have something like `#custom-marker Text` in my markdown file, I'd like to be able to render something like `<CustomMarker>Text<CustomMarker/>`. Is this possible?

I tried using the components prop, but it only allows you to change how default syntax is rendered (e.g. rendering a `<h2>` component when a `<h1>` component would typically be rendered), so I'm not sure where to start.